# how to find $\mathbb{P}[Y=0]$ given $\left( Y| X=k\right)\sim \mathsf{Poi}\left(k \ln 3\right)$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Given random variable $X$ uniform distributed on the set $\{1,...,{70}\}$ Let $Y$ be random variable such that $$\left( Y| X=k\right)\sim \mathsf{Poi}\left(k \ln 3\right)$$  calculate $\mathbb{P}[Y=0]$

---

My attempt:

I thought on finding general exprerssion for $P_Y(y)$

$$\mathbb{P}(Y|X=k)=\frac{k(\ln3)^n}{n!3^k}$$
$$\mathbb{P}(Y=y)=\sum_{k=1}^{70} \mathbb{P}(Y|X=k) \mathbb{P}(X=k)=\sum_{k=1}^{70}\frac{k(\ln3)^n}{n!3^k}\cdot k$$

I dont understand if this is the correct method because I have 2 variables and eventualy the sum will be a function of $n$ so I guess I made a mistake but I have no idea how to solve it

Comment: What is $n$? Is it the outcome of $Y$? You should have that $$P(Y=0|X=k)=e^{-0\cdot \ln(3)}\cdot\frac{\big(k\ln(3)\big)^0}{0!}$$ You wrote $P(Y|X=k)$ which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track but you need to simplify things a bit.  If the only thing you want is $\Pr[Y = 0]$, then you should compute the conditional probability $$\Pr[Y = 0 \mid X = k] = e^{-k \ln 3} \frac{(k \ln 3)^0}{0!} = 3^{-k}.$$  So $$\Pr[Y = 0] = \sum_{k=1}^{70} \Pr[Y = 0 \mid X = k]\Pr[X = k] = \sum_{k=1}^{70} \frac{3^{-k}}{70}.$$  Factor out $1/70$ and then recognize the sum is a finite geometric series with common ratio $1/3$.

Comment: the line $\Pr[Y = 0 \mid X = k] = e^{-k \ln 3} \frac{(k \ln 3)^0}{0!} = 3^{-k}.$ is exactily what I missed in this problem, still I dont understand why it should be written in this way althought I understand the defintion of poisson distribution

Comment: @Sagigever Well, you know that if $Y$ is Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, then $$\Pr[Y = y] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^y}{y!}.$$  So now substitute $\lambda = 3 \ln k$, and choose $y = 0$.

Comment: Ok I think I understand the idea here, last question, how did the factor 1/70 came? I thought $\Pr[X = k] = k$ as long $1\leq k \leq 70$

Comment: @Sagigever If $X$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1, 2, \ldots, 70\}$, then $\Pr[X = x] = \frac{1}{70}$ for $x \in \{1, 2, \ldots, 70\}$.  Each outcome of $X$ is equally likely.  What you wrote is not correct and makes no sense because probabilities cannot exceed $1$, and your equation would have, for instance, $\Pr[X = 2] = 2$.